How to Accurately Convert Latitude/Longitude to U/V Coordinates Using a Reference Point in Tacview?
Question:
I'm working on a project that involves processing flight data recorded in Tacview, and I've encountered an issue with converting geographic coordinates (latitude and longitude) into U/V coordinates using a reference point.
Context:
In the .acmi file generated by Tacview, the reference point is specified as follows:
ReferenceLongitude=39
ReferenceLatitude=37


I have a target point with the following geographic coordinates:
Longitude = 5.9498941
Latitude = 4.6735553


Using this reference point, I attempted to convert the target's geographic coordinates to U/V coordinates, which are supposed to represent the native x/y coordinates in a flat world, typically in meters.
My Approach:
I used the following Python code to perform the conversion:
from pyproj import Proj, transform

def latlon_to_uv(reference_lat, reference_lon, target_lat, target_lon):
    # Using WGS84 coordinate system, get UTM projection
    p = Proj(proj='utm', zone=33, ellps='WGS84')
    
    # Convert latitude/longitude to UTM coordinates
    ref_x, ref_y = p(reference_lon, reference_lat)
    target_x, target_y = p(target_lon, target_lat)
    
    # Calculate U and V
    U = target_x - ref_x
    V = target_y - ref_y
    
    return U, V

# Reference point's latitude and longitude
ReferenceLongitude = 39
ReferenceLatitude = 37

# Target point's latitude and longitude
TargetLongitude = 5.9498941
TargetLatitude = 4.6735553

# Calculate UV coordinates
U, V = latlon_to_uv(ReferenceLatitude, ReferenceLongitude, TargetLatitude, TargetLongitude)
print(f"U: {U:.2f} meters, V: {V:.2f} meters")


The Problem:
The conversion script produced the following U/V values:
U: -3159498.17 meters
V: -3852409.48 meters


However, the actual U/V coordinates recorded in the .acmi file for this target are:
U: 895994.12 meters
V: -315020.44 meters


There is a significant discrepancy between my calculated values and the values provided by Tacview.
Questions:
What is the correct method or projection technique to accurately convert latitude/longitude to U/V coordinates as Tacview does?
Is there a specific projection or formula that Tacview uses to achieve this conversion, given the reference point?
Are there any adjustments or alternative libraries I should consider to improve the accuracy of this conversion?

Any guidance or insights into how to properly perform this conversion would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!
What I Tried:
I attempted to convert latitude and longitude to U/V coordinates using the pyproj library in Python, based on a reference point provided in a Tacview .acmi file.
What I Expected:
I expected the calculated U/V coordinates to match those provided in the Tacview file.
What Actually Happened:
The resulting U/V coordinates were significantly different from the values in the Tacview file, leading to a large discrepancy.
